# CSS: image with bigger size than the parent but cut only on horizontal sides

Tags: html, css

I have simple CSS code which scale image inside of parent element.

Image when scaling itself is bigger than a parent. Now I need to cut bigger horizontal sides but the top side will be outside of the parent. For a better understanding look at an image.

In this image is a hover statement which I need to get:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLxE9.jpg)

I already tried on parent **overflow: hidden** but the top side will be cut too.

Like I said I need to get a hover statement like is in image preview instead of my in example code. Is there any option on how I can get it?

```css
.home-treneri {
  padding: 56px;
}

.home-treneri-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 300px;
  height: 285px;
}

.trener-card {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.trener-card:hover img {
  width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<section class="home-treneri">
  <div class="home-treneri-container">
    <div class="trener-card">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/VpiwIPSxe7FnIAm7aWS7GiB76GDhXeTjqbIst6g0dHYaXWZEyaQ6hfbUqVEuLFqZwG7lsygIjEgf1SQ338Z0djShjmotcVgw5sTQg0Ltf638227HVN7ok3UlIiaUYycmTnJ27hAB055TWk0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When I use it image is cut from the top too like overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `clip-path: inset(-50px 0 0 0);` to your `trener-card` class will give you the desired result.

What it basically does is clipping the image. On the top you allow the image to grow up to 50px `(-50px)`, while on the other 3 sides you are saying that the image will be clipped `(0 0 0)`

```css
.home-treneri {
  padding: 56px;
}

.home-treneri-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 300px;
  height: 285px;
}

.trener-card {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: inset(-50px 0 0 0);
}

.trener-card:hover img {
  width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<section class="home-treneri">
  <div class="home-treneri-container">
    <div class="trener-card">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/VpiwIPSxe7FnIAm7aWS7GiB76GDhXeTjqbIst6g0dHYaXWZEyaQ6hfbUqVEuLFqZwG7lsygIjEgf1SQ338Z0djShjmotcVgw5sTQg0Ltf638227HVN7ok3UlIiaUYycmTnJ27hAB055TWk0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try overflow-x: hidden on parent.

Comment: Now Image is cut too and now on Y is scrollbar.